# How can we use Pandas with Robot Framework

Tags: excel, pandas, automated-tests, robotframework

Using 'Robot Framework' and 'Pandas', I need to read an excel file.

1. I have installed pandas in my project using 'pip install pandas' and pandas is visible in my projects path '...venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas'
2. Now, I don't know how to reference the Pandas library into my test.robot file.

Following is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     BuiltIn
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     ExcelLibrary
Library     pandas
Library     numpy

*** Variables ***
${resetSurveyURL}  https://my-domain/resettestids.aspx
${SurveyURL}  https://my-domain/Default.aspx?sid=100
${BROWSER}  Chrome
#${num1}     4
#${num2}     4

*** Keywords ***
AccessSurvey
        Open Browser    ${SurveyURL}    ${BROWSER}
        maximize browser window

PerformAdditionOperation
        ${a}=   evaluate    ${num1}+${num2}
        log to console    ${a}

ReadTestCaseFromExcelFile
        pandas.read_excel()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read test cases from an excel file to do Data-Driven Testing,
You should habe a look to robotframework DataDriver.

https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver
This is a Library that uses pandas to create test cases from excel data.

If this is not what you want:
Pandas is not made to be used as Robot library.
You should create a small library that uses pandas.

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries

Answer (score 0):

i used this to access the pandas functions :

```
*** Settings ***
Library     pandas


*** Test Cases ***

read csv avec pandas
    
    ${DataFrame} =    Read Csv    ${CURDIR}/myFile.csv #Path to csv
    ${first_cell}=    Evaluate   ($DataFrame).iloc[0,0]
    Log To Console           ${first_cell}
    #do the same when using 'Read Excel'
```